# How to list only a part of a file name till a pattern is found

Tags: shell

I have number of below files

```
abc-git.02092018.bundle
dev-git.03052018.bundle
Abc-QA-git.03052018.bundle
```

I am looking for a command which can extract/list the file name for example : abc-git.02092018.bundle should give abc

```
abc-git.02092018.bundle should give me abc
dev-git.03052018.bundle should return dev
Abc-QA-git.03052018.bundle should return Abc-QA
```

Comment: show how are you finding those files

Comment: what do you mean "files" "files"?

Comment: So you just want to trim all characters after and including the last `-` in a string?   Try `sed 's/-[^-]*$//'`

Comment: If the name is in a variable, try `${file%-*}`.  There are only 946,345 different ways to do this, so you have a limited selection of options.

Comment: ${file%-*} worked